# NodeJS - sum async results in recursive function

Tags: javascript, python, asynchronous, recursion, promise

Hi there I have the following python recursive function that sum values from all child nodes and I want to port in NodeJS but I have some problem with async calls.

```
def getTree(parent_id, level=1):
    c.execute('select * from users where parent_id=?', (parent_id,))
    rows = c.fetchall()
    total = 0
    for child in children:
        total += getAsyncValue(child.id)
        total += getTree(child.id, level+1)
    return total
```

I tried to do this but I need probably to chain it with promises because the total count is not available while I loop as I get it from an async function

```
getTree = function(parent_id, level=1) {
  c.all("select * from users where parent_id="+parent_id, function(err, children) {
    var total = 0;
    children.forEach(function(child) {
      total += getAsyncValue(child.id)
      total += getTree(child.id, level+1)
    });
    return total;
  });
}
```

Comment: one way to more easily port this code would be ES2016+ `async/await` (which is just Promises with sugary goodness) - using just promises (and therefore better browser compatibility) is a little more involved

Answer (score 1, accepted):

without seeing `getAsyncValue` I can't provide a complete answer - however

```
var getAsyncValue = function(id) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
       // resolve some value some how
    });
};
// helper to make the getTree function "nicer"
c.allAsync = function(str) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => 
        this.all(str, (err, children) => {
            if (err) {
                return reject(err);
            }
            resolve(children);
        })
    );
};
var getTree = function(parent_id, level=1) {
    return c.allAsync("select * from users where parent_id="+parent_id).then(children => 
        Promise.all(children.map(child => 
            Promise.all([getAsyncValue(child.id), getTree(child.id, level+1)])
            .then(([a, b]) => a + b)
        )).then(results => results.reduce((a, b) => a + b))
    );
};
```

I *think* using async/await, the code can be written as:

```
var getAsyncValue = async function(id) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
       // resolve some value some how
    });
};
// helper to make the getTree function "nicer"
c.allAsync = async function(str) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => 
        this.all(str, (err, children) => {
            if (err) {
                return reject(err);
            }
            resolve(children);
        })
    );
};
var getTree = async function(parent_id, level=1) {
    let children = await c.allAsync("select * from users where parent_id="+parent_id);
    let total = 0;
    for (let i = 0; i < children.length; i++) {
        let child = children[i];
        total += await getAsyncValue(child.id);
        total += await getTree(child.id, level + 1);
    }
    return total;
};
```

Comment: yes, thank you! my problem was creating nested Promise.all i think is really verbose without using awaits